# f# Switching between different versions of parameters/properties?

Tags: f#

I am trying to define a valuetype that tracks changes in its constituents
(by the constituents informing values that use it, and use of some custom assignment operators) and then based on a modus(defined with the custon operator) updates differently.

I am relatively new to f# and have two problems:

1) use1: if the value is changed same=false and so I want to return the reference to the function and change same to true, however I seem to use the wrong syntax for match.

2)I can not shake the feeling my type is more complicated than it has to be.

I am trying to define a valuetype that tracks changes in its constituents
(by the constituents informing values that use it, and use of some custom assignment operators)
and then based on a modus(defined with the custon operator) updates differently.

```
type valtype(x) as this = 
     let reference= ref x
     let mutable value = x     
     member val same= true with get, set
     member val uses=[] with get, set    
     member this.chang1=  value<- !reference
     member this.chang2=  this.same<- false
     member val changed= this.chang1          
     member this.use1= fun a->a
     member val used=this.use1

//here the error appears
     member this.use2= if this.same then this.same<-true value<- !reference else fun a->a
    //    match this.same with
    //    |false-> this.same<-true value<- !reference
    //    |true-> fun a->a

     member this.Value
        with get()= this.used value
        and set(c)=value<-c
```

wanted behaviour:
pseudocode:

func(x)=x+3
var1 §=func(x), var2 $=func(x), var3 &= func(x)

func(x)=x 
var1(intern x), var2(intern x+2), var3(intern x+2)

Ausgabe func(1):
var1-> 1 ,var2(change:intern x)-> 1, var3-> 4

var3.orderChange var3(change:intern x)

Ausgabe func(1):
var3->1

Comment: I find it hard to understand from above what the intended behavior is. Could you provide a small example program that uses `valtype`. If you are more comfortable with say `C#` that could work and we could maybe come up with an `F#` type that works for you. When reading the text I wonder if you are looking for something like `IObservable`.

Comment: ok added an example above(still need to read trough IObservable fully)

Comment: I am pretty mystified by what I'm seeing here. Perhaps write some f# that uses the valtype.

Comment: I started using F# a few days ago after looking into it for some days beforehand so I am not sure enough in my sharp to describe my problem in it.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't answer your main question since I don't understand what you're trying to do, I can tell you that you have a syntax error in your `use2` method. This is what you wrote:

```
member this.use2= if this.same then this.same<-true value<- !reference else fun a->a
```

And this the correct way to write that:

```
member this.use2=
    if this.same then
        this.same<-true
        value<- !reference
    else fun a->a
```

Notice how each assignment expression is on its *own* line. Jamming two assignment expressions onto a single line is a syntax error: the F# compiler would read `this.same<-true value<- !reference` as "Call the function `true` with the parameter `value`, then assign that result to `this.same`" — and then the second `<-` operator would produce a syntax error since you can't assign two values to one variable in a single line.

Also, given how you wrote that `match` expression below, I feel sure that what you wanted to write in your `use2` method was `if not this.same then ...`.

Can't help you with the rest of your question, but fixing the syntax of `use2` will at least get you partway towards a solution.

Comment: Thx, I changed this and replaced fun a-> a with id and cleaned up the order of variables, however when running the code I now get a System.TypeInitializationException somewhere when declaring changed and used

Comment: "Somewhere" isn't descriptive enough for me to be able to guess how to help you. I'd suggest asking a new question about that one and giving more specifics, because that sounds like it might have a different cause.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did a lot wrong, here the current hopefully correct version of this project.

```
type Valtype(n:unit ->'T)= 
     let mutable reference= n 
     let mutable value = n()
     let uses= ResizeArray<Valtype>[]
     let get1()=
        value
     //let get2()=
     //   value<-reference()
     //   value
     let mutable get0=fun()->get1()
     let get3()=
        value<-reference()
        get0<-fun()->get1()
        value
     let set1(r:unit ->'T)=
        reference<-r
        for u in uses do
            u.Changed
        value<-r()
     //let set2(r)=
     //   reference<-fun()->r
     let mutable set0=fun(r)->set1(r)
     let mutable modi =0;
     member x.Modi
        with get()= modi
        and set(i)= modi<-i%3
     member x.Subscribe(f)=
        uses.Add(f)
     member x.Unsubscribe(f)=
        uses.Remove(f)
     member x.Value
        with get()=get0()
     member x.Set(r:unit ->'T)=set0(r:unit ->'T)
     member x.Changed=
        match modi with
        |0-> get0<-fun()->get3()`enter code here`
        |1-> value<-reference()
        |_-> ()
     member x.Force= 
        value<-reference()
```